# Flashback does not start on 20.04

Tags: compiz, 20.04, metacity, gnome-flashback

Just upgraded for 18.04 to 20.04.  Tried to log in with flashback.  Screen displays desktop for a second and immediately reverts to log-in screen.  Happens with both compiz and metacity.  Both sessions are listed in /usr/share/xsessions.  Can log in successfully to gnome-classic.  Am I missing some critical flashback extension?

Comment: Do you have `gnome-flashback.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/`?

Answer (score 0):

It does not have `Hidden=true`.
This is the contents:

```
# !/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=GNOME Flashback
Exec=gnome-flashback
OnlyShowIn=GNOME-Flashback;
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Desktop
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-flashback
```

Comment: That file should not be there unless you have put it there for some reason. Delete it. Do you have other `gnome-*` desktop files there?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions.
Deleted the gnome-flashback.desktop file from .local/share/applications and could successfully log into flashback.  But all icons are locked in place.  Icon placement is set to auto.  Tried to change it to "free" with dconf /org/gnome/gnome-flashback/desktop/icons/placement but it kept reverting to "auto-arrange-icons"
There are several gnome- files in the local applications directory:
gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop
gnome-logs_gnome-logs.desktop
gnome-software-local-file.desktop
gnome-system-monitor.desktop
gnome-system-monitor_gnome-system-monitor.desktop

and several org.gnome files.  Should any of these be deleted also???

Comment: If you don't see other problems then I would suggest to not delete other files. I don't know why they were created... Unfortunately other placement modes are not implemented - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/-/issues/41.

Comment: Spent hours trying to figure out how to change Placement mode.  Now I understand that the other modes have not been implemented.  What is the prognosis for changing this??

Comment: Sorry, there is no prognosis...

Comment: Bummer  Who do I complain to ;-)

Comment: Free icon placement works on Gnome-Classic.  Would it be possible to somehow transfer that code to Gnome-Flashback???

Comment: Please use linked gnome-flashback issue if you want discuss this problem.